how add replica bigquery on multiregion location
Small question on bigquery, for deployment infra automation, it seem  terraform with google provide doens't support yet the adding replica in case au multi region.
Google has announce few month a go, in backlog development.
i try by script with local-exec/remote-exec ressource tf, but bq seem doenst work with adding replica, or may be i have wrong syntax, but work fine on gloud console like.
ALTER SCHEMA xxxx ADD REPLICA myreplica OPTIONS (location='europe-west3')
but no in cloud shell with bq
$ bq query legacy_sql=false  'ALTER SCHEMA mydataset ADD REPLICA replica1 OPTIONS (location="europe-west3") '
Error in query string: Error processing job 'dev:bqjob_r6b3a4e9f2a33d17d_000001922856d484_1': Encountered "" at line 1, column 12.
Some idea or alternative way how to add replica on bigquery dataset by script
How trying to add a  replica (multi region) on bigquery by script for deployment infra.
terraform?  bq? other?

I think your syntax is wrong.  You had described your command as:
bq query legacy_sql=false 'ALTER SCHEMA mydataset ADD REPLICA replica1 OPTIONS (location="europe-west3")'
but I think this is correct:
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'ALTER SCHEMA `mydataset` ADD REPLICA replica1 OPTIONS (location=europe-west3)'
